# No authorization to view the ICP UI

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

I try to deploy ICP-CE env on single centos 7.3 server, the installation and setup is successful, ansible script not throw any error or warning.

But when I open ICP UI on browser and login by default admin user, the UI throw error "You are unauthorized to view this page.":

[image]

Does anyone can tell me why this happend, or how to troubleshooting?

Thanks.

Comment: Are all the pods running okay? Please list the result:
kubectl -s 127.0.0.1:8888 -n kube-system get pods

Comment: Yes, all pods running okay, please see command  output below:

Answer (score 0):

Please see command "kubectl -s 127.0.0.1:8888 -n kube-system get pods" output as below:
[root@host-10-1-241-74 ~]# kubectl -s 127.0.0.1:8888 -n kube-system get pods
NAME                                                      READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
auth-apikeys-0w95b                                        1/1       Running   0          7d
auth-idp-t9mx4                                            3/3       Running   0          7d
auth-pap-0tr3k                                            1/1       Running   0          7d
auth-pdp-bbvjl                                            1/1       Running   0          7d
calico-node-amd64-mx87h                                   2/2       Running   0          9d
calico-policy-controller-1048521425-dw59l                 1/1       Running   0          9d
catalog-catalog-apiserver-c5dfm                           1/1       Running   0          9d
catalog-catalog-controller-manager-3100032879-skgwn       1/1       Running   0          9d
catalog-ui-fk7wh                                          1/1       Running   0          9d
default-http-backend-198681862-3zw25                      1/1       Running   0          9d
elasticsearch-client-3479638665-srh08                     2/2       Running   0          9d
elasticsearch-data-0                                      1/1       Running   0          9d
elasticsearch-master-1570256108-l9b56                     1/1       Running   0          9d
filebeat-ds-amd64-1kkl2                                   1/1       Running   0          9d
heapster-1250025240-clrpr                                 2/2       Running   2          9d
helm-api-817699605-gw5b0                                  1/1       Running   0          9d
helmrepo-1682907142-57lhq                                 1/1       Running   0          9d
icp-ds-0                                                  1/1       Running   0          7d
icp-router-dql5m                                          1/1       Running   3          7d
image-manager-0                                           2/2       Running   0          9d
k8s-etcd-10.1.241.74                                      1/1       Running   0          9d
k8s-mariadb-10.1.241.74                                   1/1       Running   0          9d
k8s-master-10.1.241.74                                    3/3       Running   0          9d
k8s-proxy-10.1.241.74                                     1/1       Running   0          9d
kube-dns-1038623989-8sg4h                                 3/3       Running   0          9d
logstash-4245234969-gtwg3                                 1/1       Running   0          9d
metering-dm-653503904-56cx5                               1/1       Running   0          9d
metering-reader-amd64-rj35v                               1/1       Running   0          9d
metering-server-1157299371-wqgqk                          1/1       Running   0          9d
metering-ui-1867742967-6xn1n                              1/1       Running   0          9d
monitoring-exporter-3293343457-bddpn                      1/1       Running   0          9d
monitoring-grafana-2476181526-rr380                       2/2       Running   0          9d
monitoring-prometheus-2422752664-d42jr                    2/2       Running   0          9d
monitoring-prometheus-alertmanager-3766402458-wsmkr       2/2       Running   0          9d
monitoring-prometheus-kubestatemetrics-3025976457-9g74s   1/1       Running   0          9d
monitoring-prometheus-nodeexporter-amd64-ksnr7            1/1       Running   0          9d
nginx-ingress-lb-amd64-qbnsq                              1/1       Running   0          9d
platform-api-hz8l7                                        1/1       Running   0          7d
platform-ui-qctx4                                         1/1       Running   0          7d
rescheduler-5tj7h                                         1/1       Running   0          9d
tiller-deploy-2307655136-q8z8z                            1/1       Running   0          9d
unified-router-150v5                                      1/1       Running   0          7d